# Assert after all tests in a class have run

Tags: c#, unit-testing

We are using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting namespace to decorate the classes and methods for unit testing.
What I would like is the following:
-Keep a list of items (enum values for example)
-Test the contents of the list of items after all tests in a test class have run. If the contents is not what is expected, throw an (assert)exception.

I've tried to do this with `[ClassCleanup]` but the assert (and trace information) do not seem to come forward anywhere. Thus nobody is notified.

We want this mechanism to be in place so we can automatically (meta)test if all values/types of a certain type are used during testing. If not, the testset can't be complete. E.g. CRUD must be tested on all types derived from `Entity`. When a new `class MyEntitiy : Entity` is added, the test class should fail when no CRUD tests have been added for this type yet.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, you cannot *both* enforce test order and share state between the tests with MSTest. You may try to employ [Ordered Tests](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182630%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) with some static structures, but it's rather inconvenient. Instead of magically failing tests,
I suggest using [code coverage metrics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537628.aspx) to ensure that all code being tested.

Comment: +1 Never knew MS could define ordered tests. Enforcing code coverage is indeed the aim with the question.